# How to update database from ajax post serialize? Php, Jquery, Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I want to use update query to update my rooms table from serialize. 
But it doesn't save all. It updates only the first row of the table.

my room list in mydatabase, rooms table:

```
1   Room1   Regular 

2   Room2   Standard

3   Room3   Deluxe
```

**index.php** :

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#button').click(function(){
        var serialize = $('#rooms').serialize();

         $.ajax({
           url: 'save.php',
           data: serialize,
           type: "POST",
           success: function(json) {
              alert('saved');
                }
                }); 
 }); 
 });     
 </script>

 <?php
 $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydatabase');
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM rooms";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
 {
 $room_id = $row['room_id'];
 $room_type = $row['room_type'];
 $room_desc = $row['room_desc'];
 ?>
 <button id="button"> SAVE </button>
 <form id="rooms">
 <input type="text" name="room_id[]" value="<?php echo $room_id;?>" />
 <input type="text" name="room_type[]" value="<?php echo $room_type;?>" />
 <input type="text" name="room_desc[]" value="<?php echo $room_desc;?>" />
 </form>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

**save.php** :

```
 <?php
 $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'rooms');

 for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['room_id']); $i++)
 {
 $room_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['room_id'][$i]);
 $room_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['room_type'][$i]);
 $room_desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['room_desc'][$i]);


 if (empty(trim($room_id))) continue;


 $sql = "UPDATE `rooms` SET `room_type`= '$room_type',`room_desc`= '$room_desc'  WHERE `room_id` = '$room_id'"; // ---- it doesn't updates all. it only update the first one.

 mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
 }
 ?>
```

I tried also using insert into query and it works fine and saves all data,
but when i use update, only the first row is updated. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sorry for this dumb question.
I already found out the answer or i should say my mistake.

I found out that `<form id="rooms"></form>` must put outside while statement to
get all the data.

I can now use update query. :)